# ERROR While update android studio 3.6 "Some conflicts found in the installation area?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting this error when i update android studio through "Update and Restart" button. I've already closed all projects and running Android studio as Administration. Please help, how can I update. I've limited internet data connection.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXm3m.png)